# Using Jquery UI datepicker to filter MySQL query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to filter a query by date range using the Jquery UI datepicker, but I am always getting a SQL error. I also would like to have a submit button for the date range, if someone can also help me with that.

The code is;

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            jQuery(function() {
                jQuery( "#from" ).datepicker({
                  defaultDate: "+1w",
                  changeMonth: true,
                  numberOfMonths: 1,
                  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                    $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                  }
                });
                jQuery( "#to" ).datepicker({
                  defaultDate: "+1w",
                  changeMonth: true,
                  numberOfMonths: 1,
                  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                    jQuery( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
                  }
                });
            });
</script>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <label style="margin: 0 10px 0 20px;" for="from">From</label>
    <input style="padding: 3px; border-radius: 4px; opacity: none; background: #EEEEEE;" type="text" id="from" name="from" />
    <label style="margin-left: 10px;" for="to">To</label>
    <input style="padding: 3px; border-radius: 4px; background: #EEEEEE;" type="text" id="to" name="to" />
    </form>

    <?php  
    $from = $_POST['from'] ;
    $to = $_POST['to'] ;

    SELECT display_name as Author,
    FROM posts p
    WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND ((post_date >= $from) AND (post_date < $to))
    ?>
```

Comment: And what is $q? Where is that defined?

Comment: Also, it doesn't appear that you are setting the format for your datepicker. If you're going to put the user input straight in (which is HIGHLY insecure), you need to format it in YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Sorry, there's no $q, code was adjusted. The error is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND (post_date < ))"

Comment: Unclosed `<script>` tag...

Comment: @gustavohenke thanks, but that's not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put quotes around `$to` and `$from`

```
mysql_query("SELECT display_name as Author,
    FROM posts p
    WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND ((post_date >= '$from') AND (post_date < '$to'))");
```